# ¿Desde un controller de Laravel como separar la logica de negocio con logica de acceso a datos?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, buenas-prácticas

Soy nuevo en Laravel y no me gusta que en un controlador se haga lógica de negocio o lógica de tratamiento de datos mezclada con lógica de acceso a datos.

Si vemos el ejemplo de Codeigniter tiene los controllers y los models. Los models tienen el acceso a datos y los controllers llaman a esas funciones.

Pense que en Laravel se podría hacer algo así, como por ejemplo:

1. Un controlador que tenga el acceso a datos y otro que llame a esas funciones.
2. Un controlador que llame a otro archivo que tenga el acceso a datos.

La verdad no sé como abordar el problema por ser nuevo en Laravel y con los ejemplos de pronto estoy violando las buenas practicas de Laravel.

Comment: Si, pero esos modelos tienen las funciones por defecto que no se ven y que las utiliza el framework.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel **NO** hace lógica de negocios ni interacción con datos persistentes desde el controlador, es el programador quien lo hace, forma parte de las buenas prácticas y de SOLID.

A las personas que son nuevas en Laravel les cuesta entender un poco que Laravel no necesariamente utiliza un MVC convencional, ese patrón típico no es el implementado y se puede leer y deducir fácilmente en su documentación. Taylor Otwell (el creador de Laravel) lo ha manifestado públicamente en varias ocasiones también.

En todo caso, he trabajado con ambos frameworks y si bien Codeigniter pareciera ser un poco más rudimentario (es más sencillo para los novatos), Laravel es sencillo y a la vez robusto, su curva de aprendizaje es muy suave, siempre y cuando tengas buenas bases de programación y entiendas SOLID, OOP, patrones de diseño.

---

En cuanto al problema puntual, Laravel incluye los modelos y su ORM eloquent, en conjunto son una herramienta mucho más elaborada que las que ofrece Codeigniter. Si deseas tener una abstracción mayor y regirte al pie de la letra por los principios SOLID (al comienzo de la pregunta parece ser lo que quisieras hacer), puedes utilizar repositorios.

---

En cuanto a lo que propones:

> Un controlador que tenga el acceso a datos y otro que llame a esas funciones.

Es una mala práctica en cualquier lenguaje o proyecto que un controlador llame a otro.

> Un controlador que llame a otro archivo que tenga el acceso a datos.

Si te refieres a otro archivo como el modelo o un repositorio o servicio, entonces sí, esta es una mejor solución.

---

Al final, ten en cuenta que Laravel es solo una herramienta que no limita prácticamente nada, las posibilidades son del lenguaje, que sigue siendo PHP y los patrones de diseño los mismos que en cualquier otro proyecto.

Comment: Excelente estoy de acuerdo en que es el desarrollador quien hace la lógica de negocio y de acceso a datos desde el controlador, también así mismo es quien hace las violaciones a las buenas practicas. Los casos los puse como ejemplos pero obviamente el primero es un error o una mala practica. Según tu comentario hice lo siguiente: puse una función en el modelo que accede a buscar usuarios (por ejemplo) y retorna los datos en una variable... desde el controlador la llame y efectivamente trajo los datos. ¿Es esto a lo que te referías? ¿Esta bien realizado o viola alguna buena practica de Laravel?

Comment: Sí y no, depende como lo hayas realizado.

Comment: //Función en el modelo
public static function getUser($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        if($user == null){
            return "No se encontraron datos de usuario";
        }
        return $user;
    }


//Llamado desde alguna función del controlador
$userUnique = User::getUser(69904);
dd($userUnique);

PD: Que pena que no se como entrar al chat

Comment: Realmente un modelo en Laravel no es para eso, o no exactamente, dependiendo lo que necesites puedes usar Route Model Binding, o si eso no es lo adecuado, utiliza repositorios. Por favor revisa la documentación.

Comment: creo que haciendo `$user = User::findOrFail($id); return $user;` resolvés todos tus problemas sin agregar ningún método al Modelo y además es lo comun y como dice Shaz también podrías utilizar Route Model Binding

Comment: Leyendo sobre Route Model Binding no me sirve para lo que quiero. La función que puse es solo un ejemplo, no se fijen en que debe pasarse un id y que va a traer usuarios. La verdad lo que quiero es que la función que esta en el modelo me pueda traer hasta datos de cruces entre varias tablas, consultas personalizadas... con el fin de separar esas funciones del controlador.

Comment: Entonces está mal formulada tu pregunta, no logramos entender lo que pretendías hacer.